# Set SSRS Report Parameter value with passed Querystring value in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I have one report, in which I have 13 parameters that fetch the data from Database. I want to set only one Parameter value from Query-string URL.

For example in my case I want to set `UserID` value to passed Query-string value in SSRS report.

Is it possible to set only one parameter from Query-string and rest of the parameters will be bind with report's Dataset.

can anyone please suggest me the best solution to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: As long all your parameters have default values (which can be fetched from queries as well) you can pass only one parameter as query string and the leftover params are set automatically!

Comment: I did that way, but now others parameters (12 parameters) default value is not getting enabled. It is just showing disabled.

Comment: When you preview the report in studio, you get 12 parameters, for those you want to pass query-string values you need to enter manually values, all others need to have values by default. Check this. If you reach this status, then you are ready to pass the few parameters via query-string.

Comment: thanks, btw I was facing issue as I have set two values in Available fields - `="y"`  and `="n"` and in default values `="y"` (this is why it was showing disabled) but after removing this `"` from each values it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue because I have set two values in Available fields `="y"` and `="n"`

And In default values `="y"`

This is why it was showing disabled. But after removing this `"` from each values it is working fine now.

So we just need to use `Y` and `N`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have some query parameters and some dataset parameters...but its always good idea to create in backend itself. The reason is your fetching all data from backend and filtering out in frontend..if data is more every time report need to pull all data from backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible as long as you have default values for the other 12 parameters.